# Problem with unity-control-center in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.10, unity-control-center

I'm new to Ubuntu. I tried to find an answer in Ask Ubuntu, but I didn't find anything.
I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on my Samsung R540 laptop. Surely I did something wrong because now the unity-control-center is not working (it doesn't open if I click on the icon). I have an error. I attached some screenshots hoping they'll be useful.

[image: IMG:]
<sup>The unity-control-center application has closed unexpectedly.</sup>

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Hge.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have broken packages. Try with the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t). This should solve the problem. If it doesn't, post the result of the command

```
unity-control-center
```

It should be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: This is a translation of the error message that Igor got in the second screenshot: There are versions of obsolete packages. Upgrade the following packages and verify if the problem still exists.  **nautilus-data** **ubuntu-mono**

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a skilled Ubuntu user. How can I upgrade the packages: nautilus-data ubuntu-mono ? Thanks.

Comment: uniti-control-center in terminal gives me this error: bus error (core dump created)

Comment: To upgrade them, just do `sudo apt-get upgrade ubuntu-mono && sudo apt-get upgrade nautilus-data`

Comment: Thank you all for your support. I solved the problem by installing again Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks again, folks.